# Can't install PDF-Pro under Wine

Tags: 11.10, wine, winetricks

I am trying to install a Windows program [PDF-Pro](http://epapyrus.com/en/pdfpro4.html). I have installed this on my Ubuntu 10.10 system using Wine with no problem.

When I try to install using Wine Program Loader, the install starts and then just stops.

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 64bit

Comment: Issue is with wine, I installed an earlier version of PDF-Pro and it worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with wine, I installed an earlier version of PDF-Pro and it worked fine